# Удаленный доступ к postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Имеется виртуальная машина на винде, на ней стоит *PostgreSQL*. Локально цепляется, все хорошо, но не могу подконектиться к ней удаленно.

Конфиги самого "Postgres" правил:

```
postgresql.conf -> listen_addresses = '*'

pg_hba.conf -> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Так же расшарил порт, но ничего не выходит. в итоге пишет `: connection timed out.` цепляюсь через navicat.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: пробовали `pg_hba.conf -> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` ?

Comment: да, попробовал сейчас, но все равно, ничего не выходит

Comment: В брандмауэре подключения извне разрешены?

Comment: скажем так, на сайт который висит на серваке я могу конектиться

Comment: Это не показатель. Сайт (веб-сервер) и postgres совершенно разные вещи. Для самого postgres'а (порт 5432) разрешены подключения извне?

Comment: да, я шарил порт

Comment: Найдите как подключаются к pg через ssh. ssh-есть на виртуальной машине?

Answer (score 1):

Решение от автора.

Проблема решилась. Всё из-за моей невнимательности. Сервер арендуется на Amazon, и там помимо открытия портов в самой Windows, нужно было так же открыть порт в админке.